# Removing wocommerce notice wrapper from my theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: Screenshot of the notice]

What snippet of code should I add to my code snippet plugin to prevent this notice from showing up when somebody adds something to the cart?

The class the notice is contained in is called: woocommerce-notices-wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend turning off a function instead of hiding the output with CSS. So try this. Open your fuctions.php file and add this code snippet.

```
add_filter('wc_add_to_cart_message_html', '__return_false');
```

This code removes all notices that are printed on the cart.

If that doesn't work, try this.

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'remove_add_to_cart_message' );

function remove_add_to_cart_message() {
    return;
}
```